# Why does getText() and getEditableText() on a AutoCompleteTextView always yield an empty string?

Tags: android, string, gettext, autocompletetextview

The goal for my project is save the login ID and also, when user types in login ID if it is already saved, it should auto complete.

I am trying to save the entered values to a SQLite DB and then read it from there to populate the auto complete text view.
The problem I am facing is, on trying to read the entered text before or after clicking the sign in button, the string is always "" (empty). I am not sure why this is always empty.
I have tried to read the string in onCreate () as well as loginOnClick(View v). Both places I get an empty string.
Here is the code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private LoginInfoSQLiteOpenHelper loginInfoSQLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private String userId;
    private String passwd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //TEST ONLY
        deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);   // For testing purposes - Delete DB for a clean start

        loginInfoSQLiteHelper  = new LoginInfoSQLiteOpenHelper(LoginActivity.this);
        database = loginInfoSQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        persistLoginId("Champ");
        persistLoginId("Cambodia");
        persistLoginId("Canada");
        persistLoginId("Champ");

        String [] userNames = getAllUserNames();

        for(String str: userNames){
            Toast.makeText(this,  str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        AutoCompleteTextView loginId = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.id_text);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, userNames);
        loginId.setAdapter(adapter);
        userId = loginId.getEditableText().toString(); //always empty

        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();              

        finish();
    }

    public void loginOnClick(View v) {
        persistLoginId("Canada");
        persistLoginId(userId);
//userID = "" empty

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Sign In Button works " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public String[] getAllUserNames(){

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DB_TABLE_NAME,new String[]{DB_COLUMN_1_NAME},null,
                null,null,null,null);

        String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            do{
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME));
                str[i] = name;
                i++;
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
            return str;         
        }
        else{
            cursor.close();         
            return new String[]{};
        }

    }

    private void persistLoginId(String loginId) {

            //Check if loginID exists then do not add
            if ( !loginIdExists(loginId)){
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME, loginId);
                Log.i(this.toString() + " insertUserName", "Inserting username : " + loginId);
                database.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
            } else{
                //for testing 
                Toast.makeText(this, loginId + "  exists. Not Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }

    public boolean loginIdExists(String id) {
        String DB_SELECT_SCRIPT = "SELECT " + DB_COLUMN_1_NAME + " FROM " + DB_TABLE_NAME ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = loginInfoSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(DB_SELECT_SCRIPT, null);

        if( cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                do{
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME));
                    if(id.equals(name)){
                        cursor.close();
                        return true;
                    }
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());        
            }
            else{
                cursor.close();         
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;       
    }

    public boolean removeUserName(String userName){
        int result = database.delete(DB_TABLE_NAME, "user_name='" + userName + "'", null);

        if(result > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getEditableText()` returns an `Editable` object, not a `String`. The method you want is `getText()`

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: I've tried getText() as well. That is returning an empty string as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue of an empty string being returned from getText(). It was a minor error of declaring the AutoCompleteTextView loginId in onCreate(). Since the loginID loses scope once onCreate() is executed, when we try to read the entered string in loginOnClick(), it is read as empty. Here's what I did to fix it.

1. Declared AutoCompleteTextView loginId as a private member of the Activity -

   ```
   private AutoCompleteTextView loginId;
   ```
2. Changed onCreate() as  -

   ```
   loginId = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.id_text);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, userNames);
   loginId.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```
3. Changed loginOnClick(View v) as follows

   ```
   public void loginOnClick(View v) {
       String userId = loginId.getText().toString();
       EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
       String passwd = password.getText().toString();
               persistLoginId(userId);
   }
   ```